# cmake cache variables deleted when some change

Tags: cmake

I have a part of my `CMakeLists.txt` that sets the C++ standard:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
endif()
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

This seems to work fine... mostly. I have a build directory, which I set up via:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$(which clang++) -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
                 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17  ../gw3
```

Built my project on clang, fixed a few things, normal work stuff. Then I wanted to check to see if I broke the gcc build, so, in the same directory, I ran:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$(which g++) -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
                 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17  ../gw3
```

This emited:

```
-- Configuring done
You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
The following variables have changed:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /path/to/bin/g++
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /path/to/bin/g++
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /path/to/bin/g++
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /path/to/bin/g++
... like 20 more times ...

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
... more cmake stuff here ...
```

At this point though, `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` is set to `11` in the cache! Why? I set it on the command line to 17. If I rereun the same `cmake` command *again* (verbatim, just up-arrow, enter), *then* the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable gets set to `17` as desired. What gives?

Answer (score 3):

The conventional way to avoid this error is to set the compiler via an environmental variable, i.e:

```
$ CXX=clang++ cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
# ...
$ cat CMakeCache.txt | grep STANDARD
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD:STRING=17
$ env CXX=g++ cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
# ...
$ cat CMakeCache.txt | grep STANDARD
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD:STRING=17
```

CMake doesn't like it when you try to change `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. From the [FAQ](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#i-change-cmake_c_compiler-in-the-gui-but-it-changes-back-on-the-next-configure-step-why):

> #### I change CMAKE_C_COMPILER in the GUI but it changes back on the next configure step. Why?
>
> Once a build tree is created with a given compiler it cannot be
>   changed. There are a variety of implementation reasons for this
>   policy.

Comment: Is there a practical difference between `CXX=g++ cmake ..` and `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ ..`?

Comment: Did you clean the CMake cache in between your two CMake runs? My expectation from the quoted FAQ section would be that this should work with both the environment variable and the `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER` approach as long as you start the configure from scratch, but you should expect trouble if you try to switch compilers on an existing configuration.